# Casting byte to Enum in Java

Tags: java, casting, arraylist, enums

I'm wondering how to cast an Byte to Enum

My code is this:

```
public final EnumTest Test()
{
    return (EnumTest)data.get(1);
}
```

but it won't work because data is a byte arraylist. Is there anyway to do this like I would in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you mean byte to Enum.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public final EnumTest Test()
{
    return EnumTest.values()[data.get(1) & 0xFF];
}
```

Comment: You don't need the (int) cast, but you do need an & 0xff.

Comment: @EJP - heh, you don't think the negative array indexes will work?

Comment: Thanks! You were a great help.

Answer (score 0):

In java enums are basically just classes, in C# they are just constants (I think).
I'm not sure why you're saying:

> cast an Enum to Byte, yes Enum to Byte, not Byte to enum.

While you're getting a byte out of your data arraylist and try to return an enum though....
So are you sure you don't mean Byte to Enum?

Anyway, you *could* use the `ordinal` of a java enum to get the one you want although you might be better of with a different design.